# Passing a 'service' parameter to RocketShipIt API?

Tags: php, fedex

Is there anyone who is using RocketShipIt API? I'am currently doing some integration with FedEx web service, but it seems that I can't find where to pass a service parameter, before submitting shipment and creating label.

I am creating shipment as follows, and as is documented in RocketShipIt documentation:

```
$shipment = new \RocketShipIt\Shipment('fedex', 'FIRST_OVERNIGHT');

$shipment->setParameter('toCompany', 'John Doe');
$shipment->setParameter('toName', 'John Doe');
$shipment->setParameter('toPhone', '1231231234');
$shipment->setParameter('toAddr1', '111 W Legion');
$shipment->setParameter('toCity', 'Whitehall');
$shipment->setParameter('toState', 'MT');
$shipment->setParameter('toCode', '59759');

$shipment->setParameter('length', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('width', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('height', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('weight','5');
//$shipment->setParameter('service', 'FIRST_OVERNIGHT');



$response = $shipment->submitShipment();
```